# checkdnsrr cannot find my domain whereas dns_get_record can find it

Tags: php

I am trying to use two different functions to validate the domain/host names

when I use

```
checkdnsrr(end($domainname))
```

I get none or false response.

but when I use

```
dns_get_record(end($domainname))
```

I get my domain listed and true response

will `checkdnsrr` use different method to resolve hostnames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default record type for `checkdnsrr()` is `"MX"`.

The default type for `dns_get_record()` is `DNS_ANY`.

If your domain doesn't have an MX record, you'll get an empty response from the first call. The second call will find whatever records are available for the domain.

What you're more likely to be interested in are `A` records, which contain the site's IPv4 address. Try

```
checkdnsrr(end($domainname), "A")
dns_get_record(end(domainname), DNS_A)
```